# Volley sending multiple requests Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am sending a request to server and it causes errors. I was able to trace the error to the fact that Volley is sending the request more than once. I searched the internet for solutions, I tried all what I came across but none of them seem to solve the problem

Below is my code:

```
 public void btnLogOut(View view) {

    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Logging Out", "Please wait...", false, false);
    //cover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    String token = dbHelper.getAuth().getString(0);

    String IP = helperFunctions.getAppUrl();
    final String url = IP + "/deregister?token=" + token+ "&appVersion=" + versionCode;

    JsonObjectRequest sr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            logOut.LogOutUser();
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    if (VolleyErrorHelper.getMessage(error, Settings.this).equalsIgnoreCase("401")){
                        logOut.MakeUserLogin();
                    }else{
                        cover.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    //VolleyLog.e("Deregister GCM", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Process not completed, try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                }
            });
    sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(sr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS));
```

I used on the POST requests so it can do a retry